# using recursive function to populate an array with category and sub categories

Tags: php, recursion

i store my categories and sub categories in the same table like this , each category or sub category may have it's own sub category

```
+--------+---------------+---------------+
| id     | title         | parent        |
+--------+---------------+---------------+
|      1 | black         |             0 | 
|      2 | red           |             0 | 
|      3 | dark red      |             2 | 
|      4 | light red     |             2 | 
|      5 | very light red|             4 | 
+--------+---------------+---------------+
```

i want to store all cat and sub categories in a array in a way that they keep their parent-child relation

so i thought recursive functions are clean way to go so here is the best i came up with

```
function get_categories(){

    $array  =  array();
    $all    = $this->db->get('category' , array('parent'=>0) ); 
   // this query gets all the parent categories ( select * where parent = 0 )

    foreach($all as $a )
    {
        $array[$a->id]['category'] =  $a->title ;
        $array[$a->id]['childs']   = $this->childs( $a->id );
    }

    echo '<pre>';print_r($array); echo '</pre>';

}


 // my recursive function
function childs($parent_id = 0 , $arr = array()){

    $childs =  $this->db->get('category' , array('parent'=>$parent_id ) );
    //  this query :  select * where parent = $parent_id 

    if($childs)
    {
      foreach($childs as $ch)
      {
         $arr[$ch->id][ 'category' ] = $ch->title;
         $arr[$ch->id][ 'childs' ] = $this->childs($ch->id , $arr );
      }
    }


    return $arr ;
}
```

but i get lots of extra childs for each category even when there is no child  !
 here is the result in jsfiddle (An!!! :

http://jsfiddle.net/nkxgc4by/

Comment: That is an extremely inefficient way to go about it. If you know you're going to use all the categories from the DB in your PHP, you should just grab them all in a single select * query, then sort them into sub-arrays by placing anything with a parent set beneath its parent, in a single foreach loop.

Comment: @RyanLaBarre thanx , i'm going to put them all in one array and use that array instead of database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to return your $arr when $childs are true ;)

```
       }

       return $arr;
```

Remove only your else.

For your structure:

```
      $arr[$parent_id] = $ch->title;
      $this->childs($ch->id , $arr );
```

Replace with

```
      $arr[$ch->id][ 'category' ] = $ch->title;
      $arr[$ch->id][ 'childs' ] = $this->childs( $ch->id );
```

then you have the same structure in your childs

Comment: thanx , now it s kinda works but i get lots of extra sub categories , something is wrong ... here it is on jsfiddle !! http://jsfiddle.net/nkxgc4by/

Comment: Try my new code. I removed $arr in the childs function.

Comment: thanx it works great ! i donu why i was sending array to function

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = [
  [
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Category 1',
    'parent_id' => null
  ],
  [
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Category 1.1',
    'parent_id' => 1
  ],
  [
    'id' => 3,
    'name' => 'Category 1.2',
    'parent_id' => 1
  ],
  [
    'id' => 4,
    'name' => 'Category 2',
    'parent_id' => null
  ],
  [
    'id' => 5,
    'name' => 'Category 2.1',
    'parent_id' => 4
  ],
];

function buildCategoryTree(array &$elements, $parentId = null) {
  $branch = array();

  foreach ($elements as &$element) {
    if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
      $children = buildCategoryTree($elements, $element['id']);
      if ($children) {
        $element['children'] = $children;
      }
      $branch[$element['id']] = $element;
      unset($element);
    }
  }
  return $branch;
}
echo "<pre>";
$tree = buildCategoryTree($categories);
print_r($tree);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining *how* this solves the problem in question, so both the OP and future visitors can benefit more easily.